# Makefile: 23: the recipe for the target "allmodes" failed

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, configuration, binding, omnet++

We have an issue installing OMNeT 4.6; everything proceed well but in the final part we have this error message:

> Makefile: 23: the recipe for the target "allmodes" failed

The system doesn't ask us to tape OMNeT (like it should be). We taped it anyway and everything proceeded okay.

After that, we tried to install Castalia, but (like we had an error installing OMNeT - at least this is what we suppose-) we have another error message about liboppsim ( & we suppose that the cause is the failed OMNeT installation).

We tried the install the 4.6 version because Castalia doesn't support the OMNeT v5.x

any help guys please??
thanks in advance

OS : Windows 10

[Error msg in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Cxy.jpg)

[Error in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZI1y.jpg)

Comment: suggest you proof-read and format yor text. No-one is going to tro read that single sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the error: you should successfully build and test OMNeT++ before proceeding to install any model. You screenshot shows only, that there was an error, but the important error messages are not shown at all.

As for Castalia compatibility, here is a port that works with the latest version of OMNET: https://github.com/rhornig/Castalia/tree/topic/omnetpp54-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Note that some people have ported Castalia 3.3 to OMNeT 5.x and they report it works on Windows 10. More info found here:
https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/issues/12

In general, Castalia 3.3 is not tested on Windows 10 (irrespective of the OMNeT version), so you are treading on unknown territory, even if some people have successfully used Castalia on Windows. If you do not want to bother with these complexities you could use VirtualBox to run an Ubuntu system.